# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value....

Tags: data-conversion

I am struggling with a common error... We are trying to capture several variants of string results and convert them to a single text word 'Negative'

```
    ,(CASE WHEN max(MR_RNATest.OBSVALUE) like '%not%detected%' 
         **OR max(MR_RNATest.OBSVALUE) like '%Non%Detected%%'**
         OR max(MR_RNATest.OBSVALUE) like '%n%ive%'
         OR max(MR_RNATest.OBSVALUE) like '%<%'
         OR max(MR_RNATest.OBSVALUE) = 'N'
         OR max(MR_RNATest.OBSVALUE) LIKE '%ND%'
     THEN 'Negative'....
```

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'HCV Non Detected ' to data type int.

I've reviewed multiple topics online but I couldn't understand how to adapt them to fit my case when statement. Please help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any programming language preferences?

Comment: I would normalize the string before adding further logic, that might help you with edge cases.

Comment: SQL ... Normalize the string?